# AWS RDS not uploading general log to CloudWatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to upload the general log of an RDS instance to CloudWatch Logs.

Here are the configurations I've set:

1. Select `General log` in `Log exports` section.

[image]

2. Enable general log in parameter groups:

[image]

With the above options set, I still can't find the logs in the Log Groups of CloudWatch.

Is there anything else that I forgot to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to thie [document](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/database/monitor-amazon-rds-for-mysql-and-mariadb-logs-with-amazon-cloudwatch/), I have to set `log_output = FILE` to write logs to the file system and publish them to CloudWatch Logs.